# MVC2 - Content and scripts folders return 404

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2, http-status-code-404

I don't know what I did, but suddenly my scripts and content folders return a 404 for all items.

I thought maybe it was folder permissions, since I put the project in a folder under "my documents".  I ran VS as an administrator and I still have an issue with the style.

I ran in debug mode and there are no errors popping up.

Nothing changed in my master pages.  I tried pulling it apart piece by piece with no such luck.

When I navigate to any images/css/scripts I get a 404 error.  to prove I'm not crazy, here are my routes.

```
#region Error Friendly Names
                routes.MapRoute(
                       "AccessDenied",                                              // Route name
                       "Error/AccessDenied",                           // URL with parameters
                       new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", code = "403" } // Parameter defaults
                   );
                routes.MapRoute(
                       "NotFound",                                              // Route name
                       "Error/NotFound",                           // URL with parameters
                       new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", code = "404" } // Parameter defaults
                   );
                routes.MapRoute(
                       "ServerError",                                              // Route name
                       "Error/ServerError",                           // URL with parameters
                       new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", code = "500" } // Parameter defaults
                   );
                #endregion

                #region Redirection
                routes.MapRoute(
                "Redirection", // Route name
                "Redirect/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Redirect", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                );
                #endregion

                routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                );

                //handle all unknown routes with a 404
                routes.MapRoute(
                    "TheOneRouteToRuleThemAll",                                     // Route name
                    "{*path}",                                                      // URL with parameters
                    new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, code = "404" } // Parameter defaults
                );
```

Before you call foul on my last route, That was there before when it worked just fine.  I also deleted it as a test to see if it was it, and it isn't the culprit.

It's as if the MVC internal handling of content and scripts has stopped working.

Here is my head section

```
<head><title>My Site</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><meta name="robots" content="index, follow" /><meta name="keywords" /><meta name="title" /><meta name="description" /><link href="/Content/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="/Content/Themes/Green/Green.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="/Content/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <!--[if IE 7]>

    <style>ul#servicesbox li {height: 1%;width: 70px;}</style>

  <![endif]-->

  <!--[if IE 6 ]>

    <link href="/Content/ie.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <![endif]-->

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" /><script src="/Scripts/ddsmoothmenu.js" type="text/javascript" /><script src="/Scripts/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript" /><script src="/Scripts/Fonts/fontin.js" type="text/javascript" /><script src="/Scripts/functions.js" type="text/javascript" /><script src="/Scripts/jcarousellite_1.0.1c4.js" type="text/javascript" /><script src="/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" />

    <!-- PNG transparency fix for IE 6 -->

    <!--[if IE 6]>

    <script src="/Scripts/pngfix.js" type="text/javascript" />

    <script>DD_belatedPNG.fix('#logo img,#slider,#piecemaker_slider,#contentbar,#testibox,#servicesbox li img,.nivo-controlNav a,.nivo-directionNav a,#social-links a img');</script>

    <![endif]-->

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {

            $(".newsticker-jcarousellite").jCarouselLite({

                btnPrev: null,

                btnNext: null,

                btnGo: null,

                mouseWheel: false,

                easing: null,

                vertical: true,

                hoverPause: true,

                circular: true,

                visible: 1,

                start: 0,

                scroll: 1,

                auto: 4000,

                speed: 1000,

                beforeStart: null,

                afterEnd: null

            });

        });

</script>

</head>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the VS development web server, or IIS ?

Comment: I am using the VS development server.

Comment: I've also tried this on 2 machines - it was previously working on both of them.

Comment: Have you made any changes to your Global.asax like adding new a controllerfactory?

Comment: I have been using structuremap for my controller factory since day 1 and it was working and has not changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started pulling chunks of the web.config out and I found this section:

```
<httpHandlers>
          <add verb="*" path="*" validate="false" type="System.Web.Mvc.MvcHttpHandler, System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </httpHandlers>
```

when I removed that, it started working again.  I think it got pasted in when I was trying to make the application run in IIS6.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps something to do with this:?

```
  //handle all unknown routes with a 404
            routes.MapRoute(
                "TheOneRouteToRuleThemAll",                                     // Route name
                "{*path}",                                                      // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Error", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, code = "404" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

comment this out and test.

EDIT:
my bad. OP states that he has already tried commenting the TheOneRouteToRuleThemAll.

Have you tried setting some ignores for your static files?

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.js");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.html");
```

It looks like the following route might map to your static location

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } //   Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: As I said in my post, it isn't that.  I did comment it out and test.  I've also been using for a long time in other projects with no ill effect.

Comment: I tried adding the ignore route, and it still shows a 404.  The default mapping is standard, and I do not have a content controller.